# How to use an array in a select query

Tags: php, mysql

How do I use an array in an SQL SELECT query?

```
$some_array = [];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE '%".$some_array."%'";
```

Can I use the array in that fashion? Or will I need to run the sql inside a foreach();

My Goal: take query and remove spaces and convert to array and search a column against all the values in that array

Comment: An array may contain more than one value. How are those multiple values meant to appear in the SQL statement? (i.e. what are you trying to accomplish?)

Comment: Check out [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: @crush I am looking to use it with a LIKE

Comment: @maximl337: What is in your array?  What do you want the query be in the end?

Comment: Assuming you don't have php code but some values on a piece of paper - what query would you **manually** write (on the same piece of paper)?

Comment: How/why would you use it with a like...

Comment: The only way `LIKE` is going to work is if you are jamming entire arrays into a single column value in which case... NOOOOOOOoooooo

Comment: @Digital Chris: how about some `OR`s?

Comment: @zerkms yes, sure, that is sane. Iterate over the array, adding `OR LIKE '$val'` each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) (it's just an alternative):

```
<?php
$array = array('red','blue','green');

$sql = "SELECT * from `table` where `column` REGEXP '".implode("|",$array)."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
<?php

  $ids = [1,2,3];

  // with quotes
  // $ids_mysql = "'". implode("', '", $ids) ."'";

  // without quotes
  $ids_mysql = implode(", ", $ids);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` IN ({$ids_mysql})";
```

The result is:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` IN (1,2,3)
```

---

If you want using `LIKE` operator (I not recommend use LIKE or LIKE or LIKE....):

```
$values = ['oh', 'my', 'god'];
$all_values = "LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR `column` LIKE '%", $values) . "%'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` " . $all_values;
```

The result is:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` LIKE '%oh%'
  OR `column` LIKE '%my%'
  OR `column` LIKE '%god%'
```

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but I not recommend

Comment: Will `IN` work with strings? for eg: `IN ('red', 'orange', 'green')`

Comment: @PatrickMaciel-p4dev Why do you not recommend using `LIKE OR LIKE OR`, I ask because I am looking for rows with multiple columns that may match a value in the array

Comment: @PatrickMaciel-p4dev `SELECT * FROM users where (fname LIKE '%xyz%' OR lname  LIKE '%xyz%' OR company_name LIKE '%xyz%'`, is it bad practice to use `LIKE` against more than 1 column ?

Comment: @maximl337 Sorry for delay. I not recommend because the performance. `LIKE` operator need be used with some caution. Just that. But, yes, you can use like you said/showed.

Answer (score -2):

A less fancy solution is this, tested and works:

```
$some_array = array('a', 'b');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` ";
$i = 0;
foreach ($some_array as $one_value){
     if ($i> 0){$sql.= " OR ";}
     $sql.=   " LIKE '%".$one_value."%' ";
     $i++;
}
```

Comment: You missed the left part of a `LIKE` operator

Comment: there is no left operand yet anyway

Comment: @Loadparts: The trick is to post a correct answer in the first place, not to post just any old rubbish and edit it later...